# Select2 multiSelect dropdown issue with selecting first option

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm currently using a Select2 multiselect with selectOnClose: true, closeOnSelect: false. This is because I want to be able to click off the box and have the content I've typed into it be used as input for the box. The issue with this is that when I click on the box, it pops open the results, I then click off the box without selecting or typing anything, and it auto-selects the first option since it was highlighted.

My question is, is there a way to fix this behavior to either not auto-select or auto-highlight the first option? Or if the user hasn't entered text, it doesn't select the first option?

Current Select2 code:

```
$('#slt-dealer_branch-cbox').select2({
    allowClear : true,
    width : "135px",
    dropdownAutoWidth : true,
    tags : true,
    multiple: true,
    sorter: data => data.sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text)),
    selectOnClose: true,
    closeOnSelect: false
}).on("select2:unselect", function (evt) { // Fix for not being able to clear selection.
    $(this).on("select2:opening.cancelOpen", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $(this).off("select2:opening.cancelOpen");
    });
})
```

Comment: You could set selectOnClose to false and use the [select event](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events) to set the selected options

Comment: But what if I type something in the box and click off it? I want that input to be recorded.

Comment: Well for that you could watch the `select2:closing` event as well and check if there's text inside the input